# Change user info on the command line

Tags: command-line, users, administration

I have made a user in Mint 16 but want to change its first and last name without deleting it and starting from scratch. I know how to do it with a GUI but I want to know the terminal command alternative. I've checked the man pages of usermod but couldn't figure out how in sh.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
sudo usermod -c "Jecht Tyre" jecht
```

You can change it with -c option. -c is for adding comment

```
usermod -c "YOUR NAME" username
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of ways, usermod is a good tool that comes to mind (I have trouble with it at times).

Another is `chfn` this will generally give you a lot of options to change (phone number, office location, and other stuff). `# chfn username` should open your favorite editor for you to change things with.

There are some unsafe methods, but I don't recommend them.